# jQuery button shows and reloads iframe

Tags: jquery, html, button, iframe, reload

I have a button which when clicked the first time displays an iframe. The source of the iframe is a text log file.

I would like that whenever the same button is clicked/toggled, the iframe would be refreshed too in case the log file is updated.

Here is my code so far:

**HTML**

```
<button id="displaylog">Display Log</button>

<iframe id="ramka" src="@Url.Action("OpenFile", "File")" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#displaylog").click(function () {
        $("#ramka").show();
    });

});
```

Comment: Just use `document.getElementById(FrameID).contentDocument.location.reload(true);` to reload your iframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Reload an `iFrame` in `jQuery`

```
$( '#ramka' ).attr( 'src', function ( i, val ) { return val; });
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you much.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve it with this short piece of code
JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("ramka").src = document.getElementById("ramka").src
```

Jquery

```
$("#ramka").prop("src", $("#ramka").prop("src"))
```